# What is the base for the weak-$\star$ topology on X and $B^{\star\star}$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

1. **What is the base for the weak-$\star$ topology on $X$?**

   I understand that a base for the weak topology on $X^\star$ is:
   $$N_{\epsilon,x^{\star\star}_1,...x^{\star\star}_n}(\psi) = \{\psi' \in X^\star:|x^{\star\star}_i(\psi)-x^{\star\star}(\psi')|<\epsilon\}$$
   This is a basis that makes all linear functionals on $X^{\star}$ continuous over $X^{\star}$. However, I'm having trouble understanding how this topology extends to $X$. In particular, its certainly the case that $x^{\star\star}$ can be an evaluation functional, in which case one may write:
   $$N_{\epsilon,x^{\star\star}_1,...x^{\star\star}_n}(\psi) = \{\psi' \in X^\star:|\psi(x_i)-\psi'(x_i)\}|<\epsilon\}$$
   However this only provides a weak-${\star}$ basis for $X$ if $X$ is reflexive.
2. **What is the base for the weak-$\star$ topology on $B^{\star\star}$?** Here $B^{\star\star}$ is the closed unit ball in $X^{\star\star}$. Closure means closed in the norm of $X^{\star\star}$.

   Basically, using the insight gained from the first question, how would one repeat the same exercise with $B^{\star\star}$ instead of $X$?

Comment: It doesn't generally make sense to talk about a weak-* topology on $X$ unless $X$ is the dual of another space.

Comment: Okay -- I asked this question try to address the highlighted statement in the image (linked in next comment). To address it, I first tried to write the base of the topology I'd want to find closure in. What would one write in this case?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QBBGbsi

Comment: Write down a base for the weak-* topology on $X^{**}$, and then intersect each set with $B^{**}$.  However, if you want to show $B^{**}$ is weak-* closed, you do not need to go all the way back to the definition of the topology.  Just note that evaluation is continuous, so for each $\psi \in X^*$, the set $E_\psi = \{u \in X^{**} : |u(\psi)| \le 1\}$ is closed.  Now note that $B^{**} = \bigcap_{\|\psi\| \le 1} E_\psi$.

Comment: To be clear, when we say weak-* convergence on $X^{**}$ we mean the topology induced by pointwise convergence of functionals on $X^{**}$ with basis: $\{ x'^{\star\star\star} \in X^{\star\star\star} :  |x^{\star\star\star}(x^{\star\star}_i) - x'^{\star\star\star}(x^{\star\star}_i)\}$. If this is true, I will next have to think about how the second statement you made is a closed set with respect to the basis I just wrote. I keep having to use the definition because I find this stuff very confusing.

Comment: No, that is not what I mean.  The weak-* topology on $X^{**}$ is a topology on $X^{**}$, not on $X^{***}$.  It is, by definition, the weakest topology that makes all the maps $u \mapsto u(\psi)$, $\psi \in X^*$, continuous.

Comment: The weak star topology on $X^*$ is not the same thing as the weak topology on $X^{*}$. The weak topology on $X^*$ makes all linear functionals on $X^*$ (which is the set $X^{**}$ continuous as maps from $X^* \to \mathbb{R}$, whereas the weak-star topology makes all linear functionals on the closed subspace $S \subset X^{**}$, such that $S \cong X$ (canonically isomorphic), are continuous. This is a weaker (sometimes strictly weaker) topology than the weak topology on $X^*$

Comment: A basis for the weak-* topology on $X^**$ is given by the sets $N_{\psi_1, \dots, \psi_n, \epsilon}(u) = \{ v \in X^{**} : |u(\psi_i) - v(\psi_i)| < \epsilon, i = 1, \dots, n\}$, where $\psi_1, \dots, \psi_n \in X^*$ and $\epsilon > 0$.  However, it is almost always best not to try to use this basis to prove things, but instead to use the "weakest topology such that..." definition from my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a normed space $X$ and  a subset $\mathcal{ F}\subseteq X^\star$ we define  $\sigma(X,\mathcal{ F})$ to be the  smallest topology on $X$ such that all $f\in\mathcal{ F}$ are continous. Then one can show that the sets of the form

> $$N_{\epsilon, f_1,...,f_n}(x)=\{y\in X : |f_i(x)-f_i(y)|<\epsilon,\space i=1,... ,n\}$$

where $\epsilon >0$, $n\in\mathbb N _0$, $f_i\in \mathcal{ F}$ and $x\in X$ form a base for the topology $\sigma(X,\mathcal{ F})$.

Now $\sigma(X,X^\star)$ is the weak topology on $X$ and  $\sigma(X^\star,J(X))$ is the weak-$\star$ topology on $X^\star$, where $J:X\to X^{\star\star}$ is the canonical embedding.

Then by the above  a basis for the weak-$\star$ topology on $X^\star$ is given by the sets

> $$N_{\epsilon, J(x_1),...,J(x_n)}(\psi)=\{\psi'\in X^\star : |\psi(x_i)-\psi'(x_i)|<\epsilon,\space i=1,... ,n\}$$

where $\epsilon >0$, $n\in\mathbb N _0$, $x_i\in X$ and $\psi\in X^\star$.

Now if you want to show that the unit ball $B^\star$  is  weak-$\star$ closed in $X^\star$ you can do it in two ways:

1. Using the basis:

For $\psi\in (B^\star)^c$ there is $x\in B$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $|\psi(x)|=1+\epsilon$. Then all $\psi'\in N_{\epsilon,J(x)}(\psi)$ satisfy $|\psi(x)-\psi'(x)|<\epsilon$ and hence $|\psi'(x)|>1$ which implies $\psi'\in (B^\star)^c$.Thus $(B^\star)^c$ is weak-$\star$  open.

2. Directly from the definition:

$B^\star=\{\psi\in X^\star: \sup_{x\in B}|\psi(x)|\leq 1\}=\bigcap_{x\in B}\{\psi\in X^\star: |J(x)(\psi)|\leq 1\}$ and as each $J(x)$ is continous with respect to the weak-$\star$ topology this is a intersection of weak-$\star$ closed sets.

Hope this helps!

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Replacing $X$ by $X^\star$ then also yields that $B^{\star\star}$ is weak-$\star$ closed in $X^{\star\star}$.

Comment: For 2, note that the question is about the weak-* unit ball in $X^{**}$, not $X^*$.  I realize the idea is exactly the same, but the distinction seems to be a point of confusion for the OP, so you may want to revise your answer.

Comment: You are right. My point was  that it is less confusing to first show that for any normed space $Y$ the unit ball in $Y^\star$ is weak-$\star$ closed and then specializing to $Y=X^\star$. I have eddited accordingly.

Comment: okay, i think my conceptual problem was understanding that weak-* convergence is a "type" of weak convergence. after I got this straight, things made more sense. of course this was said multiple times by poster and commenters. thanks!